# Get size of attachment in email

Tags: java, email, size, imap, attachment

I don't have much experience with JAVA mail programming and I need help with one task.
I have this code (this is a part of all code where I load attachments; if you need to see whole code, I can send) and I need to write an attachment size to a new variable
I searched the web and found out that size could be get from getSize() function or by counting bytes of file but I don't know how can I write this codes.
Thanks in advance.

```
private long analyzeAttachment(Metadata metadata, ContentHandler content, DataPipe data, long messageId) throws IOException, MessagingException{
       long attid = IdGenerator.getUniqueID();
       Logger.getLogger(ImapMailAnalyzer.class.getName()).log(Level.FINE, "Analyzed attachemnt {0} of message {1}", new Object[]{attid, messageId});
       String attName = getAttachmentName(metadata);
       data.writeRow(attid, "Abrakadabra", attName, messageId);
       writeContent(attid, content, data);
       return attid;
   }

   private String getAttachmentName(Metadata metadata){
       if(metadata.get("resourceName") != null){
           try {
               return MimeUtility.decodeText(metadata.get("resourceName"));
           } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
               return metadata.get("resourceName");
           }
       }
       return "";
   }
```

Comment: What have you tried, what doesn't work, what's the problem with [getSize()](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/Part.html#getSize--)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code uses jakarta.mail-api. 
Usually you need to use *multipart/xxx* content type to send the email with attachments. In this case, you are dealing with javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart. 
So you can get all the body parts and check if they are attachments.

```java
    protected void processMimeMultipart(javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart mimeMultipart) throws Exception {
        for(int i = 0; i< mimeMultipart.getCount();i++){
            BodyPart bodyPart = mimeMultipart.getBodyPart(i);
            int attachmentSize = getAttachmentSize(bodyPart);
        }
    }
    protected int getAttachmentSize(final javax.mail.BodyPart bodyPart) throws Exception {
        if(Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(bodyPart.getDisposition())) {
            return bodyPart.getSize();
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I used your code (with some edits) and now I am recieving the size of attachment. But this size is like 25% higher then the real size. What should I do to recieve the real size of attachment ?

Comment: Based on the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/mail/Part.html#getSize() - Note that the **size may not be an exact measure of the content size** and may or may not account for any transfer encoding of the content. I guess you need to decode the attachment to get the exact size.

Comment: Thanks but do you know how could I do that ?